# Reading from a .txt file to a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Having a text file `'./inputs/dist.txt'` as:

```
     1         1      2.92
     1         2     70.75
     1         3     60.90
     2         1     71.34
     2         2      5.23
     2         3     38.56
     3         1     61.24
     3         2     38.68
     3         3      4.49
```

I'm reading the text file to store it in a dataframe by doing:

```
from pandas import DataFrame
import pandas as pd
import os


def get_file_name( path):
    return os.path.basename(path).split(".")[0].strip().lower() 


name = get_file_name('./inputs/dist.txt')
with open('./inputs/dist.txt') as f:
    df = DataFrame(0.0, index=[1,2,3], columns=[1,2,3])
    for line in f:
        data = line.strip().split()
        row,column,value = [int(i) if i.isdigit() else float(i) for i in data]
        df.set_value(row,column,value)
m[name] = df
```

and I end up with a dataframe of the data. I have to read more bigger files that follow this format. Is there a faster way to redo this to improve runtime?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When opening very large files, first concern would be memory availability on your system to avoid swap on slower devices (i.e. disk).

Pandas is shipped with built-in reader methods. For example the [`pandas.read_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_table.html#pandas.read_table) method seems to be a good way to read (also in chunks) a tabular data file.

In the specific case:

```
import pandas

df = pandas.read_table('./input/dists.txt', delim_whitespace=True, names=('A', 'B', 'C'))
```

will create a `DataFrame` objects with column named `A` made of data of type `int64`, `B` of `int64` and `C` of `float64`.

You can by the way force the `dtype` giving the related `dtype` argument to `read_table`. For example forcing the second column to be `float64`.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas

df = pandas.read_table('./input/dists.txt', delim_whitespace=True, names=('A', 'B', 'C'),
                   dtype={'A': np.int64, 'B': np.float64, 'C': np.float64})
```

Comment: Could you be more specific about how to use `read_table()`? The code is also doing a transformation on the data as it reads it.

Answer (score 3):

`pandas` has a good fast (compiled) `csv` reader (may be more than one)

```
In [279]: df=pd.read_csv('cr152194.csv')
In [280]: df
Out[280]: 
        1         1      2.92
0       1         2     70.75
1       1         3     60.90
2       2         1     71.34
3       2         2      5.23
4       2         3     38.56
5       3         1     61.24
6       3         2     38.68
7       3         3      4.49
In [281]: df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 8 entries, 0 to 7
Data columns (total 1 columns):
     1         1      2.92    8 non-null object
dtypes: object(1)
memory usage: 96.0+ bytes
```

Read its docs for more control options.  For example as I used it, it used the first row as labels, whereas it looks more like data.

This is better:

```
In [294]: df=pd.read_csv('cr152194.csv', header=None)
In [295]: df
Out[295]: 
                            0
0       1         1      2.92
1       1         2     70.75
.....
```

On SO there are lots of questions about reading csv files.  I've mostly dealt with the ones that use `numpy` readers like `loadtxt` and `genfromtxt`.  Those written in Python and I can outline their behavior.  But to generate a DataFrame, using this `pd` function is simpler and faster.

Same load via `np.genfromtxt`:

```
In [285]: data = np.genfromtxt('cr152194.csv', dtype=None)
In [286]: data
Out[286]: 
array([(1, 1, 2.92), (1, 2, 70.75), (1, 3, 60.9), (2, 1, 71.34),
       (2, 2, 5.23), (2, 3, 38.56), (3, 1, 61.24), (3, 2, 38.68),
       (3, 3, 4.49)], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4'), ('f2', '<f8')])
In [287]: pd.DataFrame(data)
Out[287]: 
   f0  f1     f2
0   1   1   2.92
1   1   2  70.75
2   1   3  60.90
3   2   1  71.34
4   2   2   5.23
5   2   3  38.56
6   3   1  61.24
7   3   2  38.68
8   3   3   4.49
```

`genfromtxt` with `dtype=None` determines datatype from the first data row, and then uses that to convert all the other rows.  Note the `data.dtype`, which specifies which columns are integer and which are floats.

Comment: great thanks, is always good to learn something new. how ever i timed your solution and it takes around 6 min in comparison to @SolidSnake which takes 40 seconds. i think ill stick with the faster one

Comment: Which was slow, `genfromtxt` or `read_csv`?  Looks like `read_csv` uses the same compiled reader as `read_table`; just different defaults.

Comment: `genfromtxt` i think using `dtype=None` makes is slow since evaluates the data one line at the time

Comment: `genfromtxt`, regardless of dtype, reads the file line by line (with regular Python functions), and builds a list of lists.  It converts that an array once, at the end.  The Pandas readers use a compiled `_reader`.